# Contagem de datas filtrados por dia em MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Sou iniciante no **MySQL** e cadastrei uma tabela no **PhpMyAdmin**, onde o `id` é `int`, e todos os outros campos são `text`, incluindo um campo `data_cadastro`. Fiquei em dúvida, pois haviam vários tipos de campos com nome de `date`, e na pressa, mantive `text`, pois estava gravando certinho.
Porém agora preciso gerar relatório dos dados, filtrados por dia, e os campos estão com formatação `dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss`. Preciso fazer a SQL, fazendo uma contagem dos dados de cada dia, e retornando esses dados.
Estou pesquisando, mas não achei a maneira adequada ao meu caso.

Comment: Campo somente para data = `date`, data e hora = `datetime` ou `timestamp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema seguindo as instruções que deram nas respostas/comentários.

Primeiro alterei o campo `text` para `datetime` e depois com uma consulta SQL resolvi meu problema.

```
Select DATE(data_cadastro),
count(data_cadastro) as TOTAL from CHECKIN_TAB
group by DATE(data_cadastro)
```

Depois foi só recuperar os dados em um loop, trazendo a data e a contagem de registros diários.

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa executar uma query para converter todos os seus campos  com formatação `dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss` para `aaaa-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` pois esse é o padrão adotado pelo mysql.

Exemplo de query

```
UPDATE tabela SET data_cadastro = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(data_cadastro, 7,4), "-", SUBSTRING(data_cadastro, 4,2), "-", SUBSTRING(data_cadastro, 1,2)," ", SUBSTRING(data_cadastro, 12) ) ;
```

Após fazer isso converta o tipo de campo para `datetime`

> Obs: Caso converta o tipo de campo para `datetime` sem que ele esteja devidamente formatado no padrão do MySql o valor será perdido.

Answer (score 2):

"pois estava gravando certinho". Você usou DATE?

O problema de não estar gravado certo (pressupondo o uso do DATE ou outro), provavelmente é que você inseriu dados no formado diferente de "yyyy-mm-dd". Note os traços e a ordem.
O formato para TIME é hh:mm:ss.

"The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'."

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html

Comment: Comecei a usar MySQL faz pouco tempo, ai surgiu um projeto super urgente pra fazer, e não dava pra parar e pesquisar certinho quais tabelas usar, e no meio da dúvida e pressa, fui gravando como `TEXT` pois funcionou a gravação, e não estavam previstos relatórios.
Agora com tempo, pesquisando aqui e em outros lugares que vi que foi muita burrada, e troquei pra DATETIME.